# Prove that any $n$ vectors which span $\mathbb R^{n}$ also form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would like to prove following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Any $n$ vectors which span $\mathbb R^{n}$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$

My attempt:

I will try to prove it by contradiction.

Suppose we have $n$ vectors $(\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ that span $\mathbb R^{n}$,  but they don't form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$

We know that if vectors form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$, then:

1. They are linearly independent
2. They span $\mathbb R^{n}$

Since our vectors $(\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ span $\mathbb R^{n}$ but don't form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$, they must be linearly dependent.

In other words, following equality

$$k_{1}\mathbf{v}_1 + k_{2}\mathbf{v}_2 ... + k_{n}\mathbf{v}_n = \bf O$$

Holds when not all $k$ are zero.

If we rewrite linear combination above as linear system

$$\bf Ax = O$$

Where $\mathbf{A} = (\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ ($n$ by $n$ matrix), and $\mathbf{x} = (k_{1},k_{2},....,k_{n})^{T}$, then linear system above will have at least two solutions, $\mathbf{x} = \bf O$ and $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf {b} = (k_{1},k_{2},....,k_{n})^{T}$, where at least one $k$ is not zero.

We know that

> If linear system $\bf Ax = O$ has more then one solution, it will have infinite amount of solutions.

Hence we conclude that $\bf Ax = O$ has infinite amount of solutions.

Let $\bf R$ be rref of $\bf A$. Since $\bf Ax = O$ has inf. amount of solutions, $\bf R$ will have at least one row of zeroes.

Suppose we have linear system $\bf Ax = p$ and the equivalent linear system $\bf Rx = p'$ such that

$$\mathbf{p'} = (p'_{1},p'_{2},\cdots,p'_{n})^{T}$$

And $p'_{n} ≠ 0$

We have

$$\mathbf{Rx} =  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0\\
    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2}  \\
\vdots \\
x_{n}
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    p'_{1} \\
    p'_{2}  \\
\vdots \\
p'_{n}
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Consider $n$th row of the matrix $\bf R$ (I'll denote it as $R_{n,*}$):

$$R_{n,*}\mathbf{x} = \bf{O}$$

But since $p'_{n} ≠ 0$, it follows that

$$R_{n,*}\mathbf{x} ≠ p'_{n}$$

And therefore

$$\bf Rx ≠ p'$$

Since $\bf (R \mid  p')$ is row equivalent to $\bf (A \mid p)$, $\bf Ax = p$ must have the same solution set as $\bf Rx = p'$, thus we can conclude that

$$\bf Ax ≠ p$$

In other words, there is no vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_{1},x_{2},....,x_{n})^{T}$ such that:

$$x_{1}\mathbf{v}_1 + x_{2}\mathbf{v}_2 ... + x_{n}\mathbf{v}_n = \bf{p}$$

But this is a contradiction, because we specified that vectors $(\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ *do* span $\mathbb R^{n}$. Therefore, given that $(\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ span $\mathbb R^{n}$, they *must* form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$. $\Box$

It correct?

Comment: Your assumption that $p'_n \neq 0$ seems rather arbitrary. You should be proving that there exists some vector $v \in R^n$ such that the system of equations is inconsistent. Other than that, it seems good.

Comment: If you manage to find that $v$ such that your system of equations is inconsistent, then $v$ can't possibly lie in the span of vectors in $R$, since it can't be made out of linear combinations of columns in $R$ (ie. it's not in the column space of $R$.) But $v$ is in $R^n$, contradiction!

Comment: @YipJungHon I suppose I did bad job explaining that part. Let me try another way: suppose we have some vector $\bf p'$ such that *all* entries in the vector are *not* zero. Since $\bf R$ has row of zeroes, $\bf Rx$ will have *at least* one zero entry. But we've specified that $\bf p'$ doesn't contain any zero entries. Hence $\bf Rx ≠ p'$ And from there proceed that $\bf (R \mid p') $ is row equivalent to $\bf (A \mid p)$...

Comment: Yes, that will probably work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to provide another proof that might be more intuitive. I have left my comments on your proof.

Suppose vectors $(v_1 \ldots v_n)$ don't form a basis of $R^n$, then they must be linearly dependent.

Then there exists some $(c_1 \ldots c_n)\neq (0,...,0)$, such that $\sum^n_{i=1} c_i v_i =0$, implying that a vector can be made out of linear combinations of other vectors. Take $v_n$ for instance. Rearranging the summation, we have:

$$-c_nv_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_iv_i$$

Therefore, $v_n$ must lie within $\text{span}(v_1\ldots v_{n-1}) \implies \text{span}(v_1\ldots v_{n}) = \text{span}(v_1\ldots v_{n-1})$. But $n-1$ vectors can't possibly span $R^n$.

Comment: Well, that's neat

Answer (score 0):

This is Miscellaneous Exercise 2.25 in [Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) on p 189.
All solutions are [here](https://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199654444/studentsolutions/).

The squares  supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$.

[image]